# Regex for chars between "

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

I have a string I need to find across thousands of files, but there is a slight difference in every line, so I need help with a Regex

The line im looking for is

```
<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" width="350" height="150" border="0" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat"/>
```

And it will always be the same except the alt tag, so in the case above, "Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat" is unique.

Can anyone help me with a regex that will find anything between the alt tag ""

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this should work:

```
alt="([^"]*)"
```

This will match a literal `alt="`, followed by zero or more characters other than `"` captured in group 1, followed by a literal `"`.

Comment: I was doing this in Dreamweaver and this answer helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" width="350" height="150" border="0" alt="(.*?)">#', $string, $matches);
```

The alt attribute will be in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (?<=alt=")[^"]*
```

this gives you the thing between `alt="` and `closing "`, without `alt=" and "`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:<img.+alt=")([^"]+)(?:"\/>)
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="images/online-chat.jpg" width="350" height="150" border="0" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat"/>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat
        )

)
```

Or for more attributes:

```
(?:<img\s)(?:src=")([^"]+)(?:"\swidth=")([^"]+)(?:"\sheight=")([^"]+)(?:"\sborder=")([^"]+)(?:"\salt=")([^"]+)(?:"\/>)
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src="images/online-chat.jpg" width="350" height="150" border="0" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat"/>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => images/online-chat.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 350
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 150
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lookahead and lookbehind to pick out just the value, like so:

```
(?<=alt=")[^"]*(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php
$lines =  array(
    '<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 1"/>',
    '<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 2"/>',
    '<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 3"/>',
    '<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 4"/>',
    '<img src="images/online-chat.jpg" alt="Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 5"/>'
);

$alt_array = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $alt_array[] = getSubstring($line, 'alt="', '"');   
}

print_r($alt_array);

function getSubstring($input, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match("~".preg_quote($start)."(.*?)".preg_quote($end)."~", $input, $output);
    return $output[1];
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 1
    [1] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 2
    [2] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 3
    [3] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 4
    [4] => Title Loans Antelope Valley - Online Chat 5
)
```